# Activity Indicator doesn't stop in the same method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

In the method viewDidLoad I initialize an ActivityIndicatorView.Then, in the following method I sent the activity indicator to start. When I start the app and it runs the if statement, the activity indicator starts, but when operations in the dispatch queue are performed, the activityIndicator is not stopped. Here the method:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if([indexPath row] == [_myArray count]-2){

        [_activityIndicator startAnimating];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

            //Here I perform some operations

            [self.tableView reloadData];

            [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
    }
}
```

I wish that the activity indicator is stopped after the execution of operations in the dispatch queue!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should perform your UI operations only on main thread.
Try to refactor:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    //Here I perform some operations

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

All your UI operations should be done on the main thread. That's probably the problem.